# spring boot test execute sql script once before all test

Tags: spring, junit, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I would like to populate databases once for all tests on class.

```
@ToString
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Location {
    public static final Location UNKNOWN = new Location();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String code;

    public boolean sameIdentityAs(Location other) {
        return this.code.equals(other.code);
    }
}
```

import_locations.sql (short version of catalog)

```
INSERT INTO LOCATION (name, code)
    VALUES
          ('Sydney', 'SYD'),
          ('Seoul', 'SEL'),
          ('Tokyo', 'TYO'),
          ('Hong Kong', 'HKG');
```

```
@Sql({"/db/import_locations.sql"})
@SpringBootTest
class CargoTest {

    @Autowired
    LocationRepository locationRepository;
    @Autowired
    CargoRepository cargoRepository;

    @Test
    void testConstruction() {
        LocalDate arrivalDeadline = LocalDate.of(2024, Month.JUNE, 1 );
        RouteSpecification routeSpecification = RouteSpecification.builder()
               .arrivalDeadline(arrivalDeadline)
               .origin(locationRepository.findByCode("KYI"))
               .destination(locationRepository.findByCode("SYD")).build();

        Cargo cargo = new Cargo("TRACK-001", routeSpecification);
        cargoRepository.save(cargo);

        assertEquals("TRACK-001", cargoRepository.findByTrackingId("TRACK-001").getTrackingId());
        assertEquals(RoutingStatus.NOT_ROUTED, cargo.getDelivery().getRoutingStatus());
        assertEquals(TransportStatus.NOT_RECEIVED, cargo.getDelivery().getTransportStatus());
        assertEquals(Location.UNKNOWN, cargo.getDelivery().getLastKnownLocation());
//        assertEquals(Voyage.NONE, cargo.getDelivery().getCurrentVoyage());
    }

    @Test
     void testLastKnownLocationUnknownWhenNoEvents() {
        LocalDate arrivalDeadline = LocalDate.of(2024, Month.JUNE, 1 );
        RouteSpecification routeSpecification = RouteSpecification.builder()
                .arrivalDeadline(arrivalDeadline)
                .origin(locationRepository.findByCode("KYI"))
                .destination(locationRepository.findByCode("SYD")).build();

        Cargo cargo = new Cargo("TRACK-002", routeSpecification);
        cargoRepository.save(cargo);
        assertEquals(Location.UNKNOWN, cargo.getDelivery().getLastKnownLocation());
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:file:./h2data/demodb
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: password
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
```

My question is how to execute import_locations.sql file once, because it is a static data and it would not  be changed for all tests.
currently it run it for each test , as far i know it is default behavior for @sql on class. Should i develop some custom executor on @BeforeAll method ?
What is the modern solution to populate database ?

Answer (score 0):

The `SpringBootTest`-esque way of doing this, acknowledging that `@Sql` annotations have two directives, *before* and *after* `@Test`'s, would be another sql script to undo your other one, if you simply intend for the same one to be executed before both -- i.e. to add to the class annotation; ([from the docs, something like](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/6.1-SNAPSHOT/testing/testcontext-framework/executing-sql.html#testcontext-executing-sql-declaratively-script-execution-phases))

```java
@Sql(
    scripts = "delete-test-data.sql",
    executionPhase = AFTER_TEST_METHOD
)
```

Alternatively, because you can give multiple scripts to run to the same `@Sql` directive, you can;

```java
@Sql({"/locations_schema.sql", "/import_locations.sql"})
```

If you're able to replace your `@Entity` `public class Location` with a schema definition in a "locations_schema.sql" file that runs a `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE LOCATION (...)` command.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `@Sql` annotation you can use the Spring Boot datasource initialization as follows:

1 Put your SQL file on the classpath for example in **src/test/resources**.

2 Add the profile annotation to your test class:

```
@ActiveProfiles("database")
@SpringBootTest
class CargoTest {
// ...
}
```

3 Create a property file **application-database.properties** in the test resource folder with following properties:

```
spring.datasource.data=classpath:db/import_locations.sql
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```